# input type password: Invalid chrome URI: / (firefox only)

Tags: firefox

Whenever I have a `<input type="password" />` on my website (php files) I get an error in the firefox console (not happening with chromium for example):

```
Invalid chrome URI: /
```

I decided to create a new html file and put in that simple line, to see if the problem happens by opening it with firefox (file protocol):

```
<input type="password" />
```

Exactly the same error, plus the character encoding one.

Is there any way to debug this or could it be a firefox bug?

Please, confirm if you also get the error: https://jsfiddle.net/p4ast1y5/ (I only get the error when I click Run, not when I open the link).

I'm using Firefox version 50.1.0-1 on Manjaro Linux (Arch). And I tried restarting Firefox with addons disabled (Firefox menu -> Open Help Menu -> Restart with Add-ons Disabled...).

Comment: I don't get the error when viewing/running [that JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p4ast1y5/). I tried with both Firefox 50.1.0 and Firefox 52.0a2 (the current Developer Edition) on Windows 10, x64. From the error I investigated for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37314236/3773011), it appears likely that this is due to an add-on. Have you tried this using a [new profile without any add-ons](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles), or disabling all the add-ons you have installed?  What version of Firefox are you using? On what OS?

Comment: I'm using Firefox 50.1.0-1 on Manjaro Linux (Arch) and yes I already tried restarting with addons disabled (Firefox menu -> Open Help Menu -> Restart with Add-ons Disabled...)

Comment: Same problem here using FF 51.0.1, on Windows 8. Answer is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37021640/how-to-get-a-stack-trace-for-invalid-chrome-uri-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using firefox, but I don't seem to get that error. Maybe it's a bug in your version of Firefox

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).